# Django, Docker, Nginx, cant find static file

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-staticfiles

I just cant wrap my head around how to properly write a nginx.conf file. My nginx container in docker keeps giving me error

```
2022/10/03 12:33:28 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/usr/src/app/staticblog/style.css" failed 
(2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: ,
 request: "GET /static/blog/style.css HTTP/1.1",
 host: "localhost:1337", referrer: "http://localhost:1337/profile/login"
```

[image: but the file clearly exists]

nginx.conf file

```
upstream blog {
    server back:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80; 
location /{
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://blog;
}

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }


    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/media;
    }

}
```

I feel like im just writing conf file wrong, but I cant wrap my head around directories in docker and how to properly manage them

UPDATE: as @HemalPatel mentioned, I messed some slashes. Now I think I might as well got confused with setting.py file xD

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "blog/static/",
]
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Im so sorry its such a dumb question

UPDATE 2:

nginx container error log:

```
72.21.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2022:13:52:32 +0000] "GET /profile/login HTTP/1.1" 200 8285 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0" "-"
172.21.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2022:13:52:32 +0000] "GET /static/blog/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost:1337/profile/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0" "-"
172.21.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2022:13:52:32 +0000] "GET /docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 2542 "http://localhost:1337/profile/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0" "-"
```

Django container log

```
Not Found: /docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg
```

Comment: `alias /usr/src/app/static/` try this. looks like you forgot to add slash in the end
`"/usr/src/app/staticblog/style.css"` thats why it shows `staticblog` instead `static/blog`

Comment: @HemalPatel oh thanks, im so embarrassed xD but problem is still persistent

Comment: restarted nginx? `sudo systemctl restart nginx` share error log again if its not working.

Comment: @HemalPatel I restarted it in docker, did the docker down -v, re-built it and ran again. also just checked, I dont even have nginx outside the docker :D

Comment: can you check error log again?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: @HemalPatel I added logs, but they dont really give much more info :(
fixed STATIC_URL as well with clearing and rebuilding containers